# Why can't I get my tsconfig paths to work in VSCode?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm building a Discord bot and my VS Code project doesn't seem to be able to find my module imports when using tsconfig paths. The bot still loads fine but I imagine none of the code using these paths will actually work.

The errors aren't really super helpful as it's not telling me exactly *why* it's not working or maybe I just don't understand what exactly it's complaining about; just that I'm getting `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` errors. I've included the errors themselves and my tsconfig.json  - I've been futzing with includes, baseUrl, rootDir and I've given up googling to try and figure out how all this works. If you are able to help I'd love an explanation on exactly what's going on here?

Debug Console Errors:

```
Debugger attached.
Error when loading '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/mute.js': Error: Cannot find module '#util/functions'
Require stack:
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/mute.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/lib/strategies/LoaderStrategy.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/index.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/lib/utils/application-commands/ApplicationCommandRegistries.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/index.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/FutabaClient.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/FutabaBot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/mute.js:10:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/mute.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/lib/strategies/LoaderStrategy.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/index.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/lib/utils/application-commands/ApplicationCommandRegistries.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/index.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/FutabaClient.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/FutabaBot.js'
  ]
}
Error when loading '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/kick.js': Error: Cannot find module '#util/functions'
Require stack:
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/kick.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/lib/strategies/LoaderStrategy.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/index.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/lib/utils/application-commands/ApplicationCommandRegistries.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/index.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/FutabaClient.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/FutabaBot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/kick.js:17:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/kick.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/lib/strategies/LoaderStrategy.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/index.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/lib/utils/application-commands/ApplicationCommandRegistries.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/index.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/FutabaClient.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/FutabaBot.js'
  ]
}
Error when loading '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/ban.js': Error: Cannot find module '#util/functions'
Require stack:
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/ban.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/lib/strategies/LoaderStrategy.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/index.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/lib/utils/application-commands/ApplicationCommandRegistries.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/index.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/FutabaClient.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/FutabaBot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/ban.js:17:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/commands/moderation/ban.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/lib/strategies/LoaderStrategy.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/index.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/lib/utils/application-commands/ApplicationCommandRegistries.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/index.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/FutabaClient.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/FutabaBot.js'
  ]
}
Error when loading '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/listeners/ready.js': Error: Cannot find module './utils'
Require stack:
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/util/Timers.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/ModerationService.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/listeners/ready.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/lib/strategies/LoaderStrategy.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/index.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/lib/utils/application-commands/ApplicationCommandRegistries.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/index.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/FutabaClient.js
- /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/FutabaBot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/util/Timers.js:6:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/util/Timers.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/ModerationService.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/listeners/ready.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/lib/strategies/LoaderStrategy.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/pieces/dist/index.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/lib/utils/application-commands/ApplicationCommandRegistries.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/@sapphire/framework/dist/index.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/lib/FutabaClient.js',
    '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/dist/FutabaBot.js'
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "extends": "@sapphire/ts-config",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "types": ["node"],
        "inlineSources": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "#util/*": ["lib/util/*"],
            "#lib/*": ["lib/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["."]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have only configured your paths in your `tsconfig.json`. These are **runtime** errors thrown by Node.

The solution is to also define your path aliases in your `package.json` like so:

```json
{
    "imports": {
        "#lib/*": "./dist/lib/*.js",
        "#util/*": "./dist/lib/util/*.js",
    },
}
```

Note how this references the files in `dist` which is the output directory for your TypeScript code, and where Node actually runs the code from.

For more information see the NodeJS documentation on using subpath imports: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/packages.html#subpath-imports